# WebClient exception when UploadValues

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

I want to call a WebClient like this:

```
using (TimeoutWebClient client = new TimeoutWebClient())
            {
                System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection reqparm = new System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection();
                reqparm.Add("email", email);
                reqparm.Add("pass", password);
                Debug.Log("5");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg))
                        reqparm.Add(arg, "please");

                Uri url = new Uri(URL);
                byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);
                Debug.Log("6");
                string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
                // Debug here
                return responsebody;
            }
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Timeout while request, retry !");
            Debug.Log("7");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Exception while request: " + e.Message + e.StackTrace);
            return "Error";
        }
```

but when I run this, sometimes it make a a weird exception which goes like this:

```
Exception while request: An error occurred performing a WebClient request.  at System.Net.WebClient.UploadValues (System.Uri address, System.String method, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection data) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Net.WebClient:UploadValues (System.Uri,string,System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)
```

and I don't really know what it mean so if someone already encounter a such strange exception, tell me :X . (I'm making a video game and that's the login post request)

PS: Under Unity and .NET 2.0 but it's almost the same ^^

EDIT: Here is the full log:

```
Message =  The request timed out   Help link =    Source = System   StackTrace =   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

EDIT: And here is the TimeoutWebClient class:

```
    public class TimeoutWebClient : WebClient
    {
    private int _timeOut = 7000; // 7s
    public int TimeOut
    {
        get
        {
            return _timeOut;
        }
        set
        {
            _timeOut = value;
        }
    }
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        WebRequest webRequest = base.GetWebRequest(address);
        webRequest.Timeout = _timeOut;
        if (webRequest is HttpWebRequest)
        {
            (webRequest as HttpWebRequest).KeepAlive = false;
            (webRequest as HttpWebRequest).Timeout = _timeOut; //(tried different values)
        }
        return webRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: it appears to be something to do with the timeoutwebclient. Without knowing what that class is doing, I think you're stuck

Comment: @SimonHalsey I add the TimeoutWebClient at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, I decided to use the `WWW` class from Unity API instead of .NET API because it seems to be optimised. If you want to know the code I'm using, here it is:

```
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("email", email);
    form.AddField("pass", password);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(arg))
        form.AddField(arg, "please");

    WWW www = new WWW(URL, form);
    // Wait until the request has been sent
    yield return www;

    if (www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW text = " + www.text);
        if (callback(www.text))
        {
            // we are logged
        }
        else
        {
            // we arn't
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It means your request is taking longer than 7 seconds to connect. Either the URL you are connecting to is incorrect or there is a issue with the server.

Comment: I know that Sherlocks ! The problem is that a strange timeout happens and I don't see where !

Comment: The error happens on `byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(url, "POST", reqparm);` the value of `url` is the problem. Either the URL is wrong or the server that exists at that url is non-functioning. I would reccomend using the debugger and putting a breakpoint in at that line and see what the value of `url` is, perhaps it is not the value you are expecting it to be. Are you using Visual Studio or Mono Develop as the C# editor with Unity? The instructions for debugging is different for each.

Comment: I know it work, I host it on http://ovh.com/ , I wrote this script myself and I checked it manually, it work well. And the problem isn't there, because half time, it work so the problem come from timeout. I define the url manually upward in the code so I know the url format isn't the problem

Answer (score -1):

Why you're not using HttpClient instead, 
here is a simple code of Get/Post request using httpClient and Json.net

```
     public async Task<T> MakeHttpClientRequestASync<T>(string requestUrl, string authenticationToken,
        Dictionary<string, string> requestContent, HttpMethod verb, Action<Exception> error)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { NoCache = true };
        HttpResponseMessage response;

        var returnVal = default(T);

        try
        {
            if (verb == HttpMethod.Post)
            {
                response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(requestContent));
            }
            else
            {
                response = await httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl);
            }

            var resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            returnVal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(resultString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error(ex);
        }

        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @esiprogrammer but as I wrote one the initial question: ---> " PS: Under .NET 2.0 but it's almost the same ^^ " <--- and System.Net.Http don't exist in .NET 2.0 and I can't upgrade (compatibility etc, I can't decide)